# Retrieve Row Count from a SqlDataSource by converting into a DataView

Tags: asp.net, listview, sqldatasource, dataview, rowcount

I had some difficulties to retrieve the Total Row Count from a SqlDataSource. I used the results from the SELECT statement in the SqlDataSource to create a ListView, but got stuck to produce some code that would let me easily get the Total Row Count. I won't show all the different code i used, but show you the easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are binding your `SqlDataSource` to a `ListView`, why not simply getting the count from your `ListView` instead?

```
LabelRows.Text = ListView1.Items.Count
```

Comment: Hanlet,
I made some mistakes in code behind which let me create redundant methods to retrieve stuff. It's as easy as you mention. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming i have a SqlDataSource named 'dsResults' that SELECTS certain records from a DB Table. Below code retrieves the Total Row Count from that SqlDataSource through a DataView and let's you display it in a Label or use it within a CASE statement (executed at Page_Load):

```
Dim dssa As New DataSourceSelectArguments()
  dssa.AddSupportedCapabilities(DataSourceCapabilities.RetrieveTotalRowCount)
  dssa.RetrieveTotalRowCount = True
Dim dv As DataView = DirectCast(dsResults.[Select](dssa), DataView)
LabelRows.text = dv.Table.Rows.Count

Select Case dv.Table.Rows.Count
  Case 0
    panelResults.Visible = False
End Select
```